# How to make json in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have following data:

> > 0.485431503455,1.88492294876
> >     2.35886680948,1.11511483636

I need to covert this data into following format in python.

> > [0.485431503455,1.88492294876]
> >     [2.35886680948,1.11511483636]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> stri = "0.485431503455,1.88492294876"
>>> stri = [float(i) for i in stri.split(",")]
>>> stri
[0.485431503455, 1.88492294876]
```

I don't know what you meant by make json in python.

But I guess you probably want to use https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html